# how to code my bot to generate random images from one command

Tags: python, discord.py

I have looked before deciding to make this post. I have tried some codes from answers, but they have not worked for me. Note that I am new with coding in general; I started using Python for about a week now. I managed to code my Discord bot to generate random images from one command, however I don't think I made it correctly. The images are sent at random, but their links show in the bot's messages. Here is the code I have for it:

```
client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.upper().startswith("?DOG"):
        jessie1 = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/432563417887277060/484484259386621993/22B25E7A-3157-4C23-B889-47ECFE8A15A9.jpg"
        snowy = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/487045791697862666/487390822485065749/824B6151-E818-49A4-A564-C2C752ED6384.jpg"
        await client.send_message(message.channel, random.choice([snowy, jessie1]))
```

I am using two images as examples for now as there are a lot more that I do not want to include all at once.

I am able to generate these two images at random by using one command, but I don't know how to code so that their links won't appear in the bot's message as it sends the images.

I want to know if there is a way to do so without making a huge change to the code that I have at this moment. However, if there is an efficient/correct way of doing it, I will gladly take your advice for better experience.

If all goes well, I would also like to add a message for the bot to say when it sends those images. I do have an idea on how to do so, but I need to solve my first issue first xD

Comment: Please consider editing this question to address the code formatting. It matters in python as different indentation carries different meaning, but even when it doesn't matter it makes the code easier for potential answerers to read.

Comment: Edited. Thank you for notifying me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you please review it again though, because it currently contains a syntax error (see the line after the if statement).

Comment: Ahh I'm not so sure on what's the problem. I copied and pasted it and I didn't receive any syntax errors when I ran it prior. I got my answer already though ^^

Comment: I'm glad you got your answer - but StackOverflow is about helping not just the person asking the question, but others who have the same question. So, for the sake of other people who have the same problem I've edited your question. Please have a quick look at the diff for your learning. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=upload#how-do-i-upload-an-image) you can't upload an image like you would from a local source so you can either

Upload from a local source using `send_file`

```
await client.send_file(message.channel, 'my_image.png')
```

or

Embed the URL

```
import discord

embed = discord.Embed()  
embed.set_image(url = random.choice([jessie1,snowy]))  
await client.send_message(message.channel,embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

All I know about "discord" is what I've read in the last 30s, but here's some things that come to mind:

Where does the "client" object come from? If something like showing the link vs not showing is even controllable on your end, I would bet it's an option you could set on the client. Is there a `client.someattr`? like `client.show_link=False`? Or, is there something you can pass to the constructor?

```
client = Client(foo, bar, show_links=False)
```

Or... Maybe, instead of sending text (which is what you're doing), you want to construct and send some sort of "image" object...?

```
img1 = Image(url='...')
img2 = Image(local_file='...')
client.send_message(message.channel, random.choice([img2, img1]))
```

Note these are 100% guesses, without reading the docs. This is all just based on familiarity with many different libraries, APIs.

I would guess the same for the issue about notifying you. I'd need to see more of the docs. It's also possible that this is not something you have control over, the other end will see this whether you like it or not

Answer (score 0):

Inside your command, you should create a list of Image objects, and `random.choice` it.

As stated above, you should read the docs before asking here. Also, Stack Overflow isn't the way to get quick answers, that is the discord.py support server at https://discord.gg/r3sSKJJ.
As a final note, a new version of the library will soon be released that introduces a number of breaking changes, which can be read about [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html).